# How to get iPhone device details when it is connected to a Windows machine?

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows

I want to get the details (OS,version,UDID...) of the device (iPhone) when it is connected to a Windows machine. The only thing here is either using iTunes or another way.

I want this done from command line (NO GUI Tool).

Answer (score 2):

You can find the details (OS version etc.) simply by going to Settings > General > About on your iPhone.

Your UDID can be mailed to you with this free app http://itunes.apple.com/app/ad-hoc-helper/id285691333?mt=8 if you don't want to connect to iTunes and have the information shown.

AFAIK there is no easy way of finding the UDID through CMD on a Windows, but you can try and navigate to this path through it:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB

This should show the UDID of the iPhone, if it has been connected through USB. Bare in mind there are many lines inside the folder, but the files referring to iDevices have 40 digits in it.

Comment: I want to get the Os version details also without having any manual interaction with the phone. Is there any possibility of accessing these details using .NET from windows machine? NOTE:- My device is a jail broken one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the UDID of iOS devices backed up with iTunes you might look at the iTunes backup directories:

Windows XP:
\Documents and Settings(username)\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\

Windows Vista and Windows 7:
\Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\

**On Mac I type:**

```
ls "Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/"
```

This gives my UDID as a directory.

**On Vista / Win 7 you might try this in the Windows command line:**

```
dir "%appdata%\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\"
```

**Or on XP:**

```
dir "%appdata%\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\"
```

I would like to know if this works, thanks! I figured this out from http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4946